# intercept and Cancel volume button press globally

Tags: java, android, events, button

I am trying to intercept the volume keys globally (screen off and outside the app) so far I can detect the button press, but I can't work out how to cancel it. Here is my code so far

```
public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
private static final String TAG = "SettingContent";
int previousVolume;
Context context;

public SettingsContentObserver(Context c, android.os.Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
    context = c;

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    previousVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

@Override
public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
    return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(true);

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    int delta = previousVolume - currentVolume;

    if (delta > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Decreased");
        previousVolume = currentVolume;
    } else if (delta < 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Increased");
        previousVolume = currentVolume;
    }
}
```

}

I need to cancel the volume event so that the volume doesn't change.

Comment: I am curious about one situation, what if there is another app that did the opposite thing of your app in the same device?

Comment: That could cause issues... But I will face that when we get there... Any Ideas how to cancel it?